# Let $X$ be a metric space. Suppose $\{p_n\}$ and $\{q_n\}$ are Cauchy sequences in $X$. Show that $\{d(p_n,q_n)\}$ converges.

Tags: metric-spaces, real-numbers

I had some issues proving this, so I relaxed the conditions to prove the statement in $\mathbb{R}$ first. Here is my attempt:

Note: I used the following theorem:

**Theorem**. Every Cauchy sequence of real numbers converges.

**Proof**. By the theorem, we know $\{p_n\}$ and $\{q_n\}$ converges since they are Cauchy. So by definition,

$(1)$ $p_n \rightarrow p$ for given $\epsilon > 0,\ \exists N_1>0$ such that $d(p_n,p)< \epsilon /2$.

$(2)$ $q_n \rightarrow q$ for given $\epsilon > 0,\ \exists N_2>0$ such that $d(q_n,q)< \epsilon /2$.

Let $N> max(N_1,N_2)$. So $\forall n \geq N$,
$$d(p_n,q_n) \leq d(p_n,p) + d(p,q) + d(q_n,q)\ (*)$$
$$< \epsilon /2 + d(p,q) + \epsilon /2$$
$$\Rightarrow d(p_n,q_n) - d(p,q) < \epsilon\ (1)$$
Similarly, mult. $(*)$ by $-1$ and rearrange to get
$$d(p,q) - d(p_n,q_n) > \epsilon\ (2)$$
Thus, by $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$|d(p_n,q_n) - d(p,q)| < \epsilon$$
Hence, $d(p_n,q_n) \rightarrow d(p,q)$. $□$

Now, how can I generalize it to any metric space $X$? For some reason, I think it cannot be done. Thank you!

Comment: Show that $d(p_n,q_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use the fact that $p_n,q_n$ converges in your proof because it doesn't hold unless $X$ is a complete metric space. So instead, try to show that if $p_n,q_n$ are Cauchy in $X$ then $d(p_n,q_n)$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ and then use the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete so every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges. To do that, try to estimate

$$ \left| d(p_n,q_n) - d(p_m,q_m) \right| $$

in terms of $d(p_n,p_m), d(q_n,q_m)$ using the triangle inequality and then show that this is Cauchy because $d(p_n,p_m), d(q_n,q_m)$ are Cauchy.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Here is my attempt (again!):

Proof. Let $\{p_n\}$ and $\{q_n\}$ be Cauchy in $X$. Then,

$(1)$ $p_n \rightarrow p$ for given $\epsilon > 0,\ \exists N_1>0$ such that $d(p_n,p_m)< \epsilon /2,\ \forall n, m> N_1$.

$(2)$ $q_n \rightarrow q$ for given $\epsilon > 0,\ \exists N_2>0$ such that $d(q_n,q_m)< \epsilon /2,\ \forall n, m>N_2$.

Let $N> max(N_1,N_2)$. So $\forall n \geq N$,
$$d(p_n,q_n) \leq d(p_n,p_m) + d(p_m,q_m) + d(q_m,q_n)\ (*)$$
$$< \epsilon /2 + d(p_m,q_m) + \epsilon /2$$
$$\Rightarrow \boxed{d(p_n,q_n) - d(p_m,q_m) < \epsilon}\ (*)_1$$
(cont.)

Comment: (cont.)

Similarly, multiply $(*)$ by $-1$ and get
$$-d(p_n,q_n) \geq -d(p_n,p_m) - d(p_m,q_m) - d(q_m,q_n)$$
$$ d(p_m,q_m) - d(p_n,q_n) > -\epsilon /2 - \epsilon /2$$
$$\Rightarrow \boxed{d(p_m,q_m) - d(p_n,q_n) > \epsilon}\ (*)_2$$

By $(*)_1$ and $(*)_2$ we get
$$|d(p_n,q_n) - d(p_m,q_m)| < \epsilon$$
Thus, we have shown that $d(p_n,q_n)$ is Cauchy... in $\mathbb{R}$.
Hence, by the completion of $\mathbb{R}$, $d(p_n,q_n)$ converges.
QED.

Is my attempt okay?

Comment: @CuriousMathStudent: Yes, but you shouldn't write $p_n \to p$ because it is not true (and you don't use it) and similarly for $q_n \to q$. Also, it should be $-\varepsilon$ in the second starred equation.

Comment: Oh right! I forgot being Cauchy doesn't imply convergence unless we are in a complete metric space. Thank you for very much for your help!